# How to convert a whole array from strings to integers/numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to make it so that rather than 1+1=11 my code will return 1+1=2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var  arr = [];                              

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {              
  arr.push(prompt('Enter GTIN Digit ' + (i+1))); 
}

alert('Full GTIN: ' +  (arr [0]*3)+(+ arr [2]*3)+(arr [4]*3)+(arr [6]*3) + (arr [1])+(arr [3])+ (arr [5])             );  

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one character you need to add: a `+` (unitary plus) before the `prompt`:

```
arr.push(+prompt('Enter GTIN Digit ' + (i+1)));
```

This will do the conversion.

Secondly, you need to avoid converting it back to string in your `alert`. Put the whole calculation between brackets or else the first string will make all the  `+` act as string concatenation:

```
alert('Full GTIN: ' + (arr[0]*3+arr[2]*3+arr[4]*3+arr[6]*3+arr[1]+arr[3]+arr[5]));
```

Or, using a `reduce`:

```
alert('Full GTIN: ' + arr.reduce((s, d, i) => s+(i%2?d:d*3), 0));
```

#### Convert the array

The unitary `+` solution seems the best to me, but if -- like you put in the title -- you really want to first build the array of strings and then convert the values, then use this statement:

```
arr = arr.map(Number);
```

#### Remarks

- It is not user-friendly to ask repeated input via `prompt`. The user cannot interrupt that sequence or go back. Better is to use the `input` element with the `number` type.
- You would need to validate the input. As soon as you have a `NaN` instead of a number, or the input consists of multiple digits instead of one, the calculation cannot work correctly, and so there is no use to finish the whole input cycle.

Comment: will be NaN if not validating numbers though

Comment: Indeed, ... it would be wrong to assume any numerical value in that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response, worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt()

```
parseInt(1)+parseInt(1)
```